# Airplay speakers stop playing when VPN connection is established

Tags: itunes, vpn, airplay

I have Zeppelin Air from B&W which works great most of the time. However during VPN connection to different work places during VPN connection Airplay stops playing. If I then go to iTunes and play next song it starts to work again. My VPN connections don't have Default VPN Gateway set so there's really nothing that should be affecting AirPlay. Is this normal? Any workarounds ?

Comment: Which VPN client are you using? You could also look into updating the Zeppelin's firmware if you haven't already.

Comment: I've updated Zeppelin's firmware and I'm using builtin Windows 7 VPN's. No matter to which gateway (client) I connect it always stops playing music and as soon as ITunes notices that new vpn is connected it stops playing music and pauses the song. It seems more like ITunes being the problem here.